# How to Create Buttons With Disable Enable Option in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I want to create a custom page in NSIS. In that page I need to create some buttons... Those buttons may be disable or enable mode based on a condition...  Following is the code for create button

```
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateButton} 275 1 20% 12u "Stop Service"
Pop $BUTTON
GetFunctionAddress $0 StopService
nsDialogs::OnClick $BUTTON $0
nsDialogs::Show
```

${NSD_CreateButton} option will create the button with enable mode... But I want o create with disable mode.. I have referred the links, but I could not able to find the solution... How can I achieve this on loading the page itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after the `Pop $BUTTON`, send a disabling message to the button:

```
EnableWindow $BUTTON 0
```

Comment: Already I have tried this option but used in some other line.. Now its working fine.. Thank you Seki...

Comment: Seki I have also another doubt on the buttons.. Suppose I have so many buttons in my page... A button which is clicked should be disble.. How to achieve this? That is in an Onclick event of the button it should be disable.... Could u please help me how to do this?

Comment: The `pop $button` is getting the handle of the button that is created with `${NSD_CreateButton}`. If you have multiple buttons, you should define as many variables as buttons, to store each button's handle and be able to access it later from a callback.